# React Native Navigation StackNavigator load between different StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have the following StackNavigator

```
export const OauthNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Login",
            headerLeft: null,
        },
    },
    ResetPassword: {
        screen: ResetPassword,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Reset Password",
            headerLeft: null
        },
    }
});
```

And then I have my main navigation

// Main navigation StackNavigator

```
export const MainScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: TabsNavigation,
    },
    Drawer: {
        screen: MainDrawerNavigator
    }
});
```

I'm using redux how would I load the different ones

Here is my reducer

```
const AppReducer = combineReducers({
    nav: (state = initialNavState, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'LOGIN':
                return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }), state);
            case 'LOGOUT':
                return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }), state);
            case 'RESET_PASSWORD':
                return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ResetPassword' }), state);
            case 'MAIN':
                return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Main' }), state);
            case 'TEAM':
                return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Teams' }), state);
            default:
              return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
        }
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how would I load the different ones"? What error are you running into and what have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I'm moving to flex router react navigation is just not good